# What characters are not allowed in SkyDrive file names?

Tags: windows-8, filesystems, onedrive, cloud

I'm adding my music to SkyDrive, and a file failed to sync with this message:

> Error: This file name contains characters that aren't allowed.
>   Resolution: Please change the file name so it doesn't begin or end with a space, or end with a period.

The file name already doesn't begin or end with a space, or end with a period. The specific file name in question is:

```
Weaver At The Loom Before Now_ Was Then_01_Were Wild Animals (We Always Were).mp3
```

Since the suggested resolution isn't applicable, why is the real reason this filename doesn't work? And where can I find resources for resolving future issues? Note that the file syncs correctly in Dropbox.

Comment: Did you try to shorten the filename?

Comment: Try renaming it file01.mp3, then rename it back.

Comment: According to the Microsoft support forum, the maximum filename length for Skydrive is 230 characters. Yours being 77, I doubt that is the problem. Are you sure there isn't a space at the end of the filename? According to the following guide, that would cause an issue: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/skydrive/upload-file-cant-faq

Comment: @OliverG: I'm absolutely sure. I ended up re-typing the name from scratch, and it uploaded then. Maybe one of the characters looked normal, but was actually an unusual character?

Comment: "Maybe one of the characters looked normal, but was actually an unusual character?" - This was what immediately came to my mind as well when I read your question completely. I was going to advise you to copy-paste into Notepad, then save as ANSI and see if it complained. If there was a Unicode character, it would have either complained, or on re-opening the file you would have found some invalid ANSI character replaced with another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name may not begin or end with a space, end with a period, or include any of these characters: `/ \ < > : * " ? |`

These names aren't allowed for files or folders: AUX, PRN, NUL, CON, COM0, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT0, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9

Source: [SkyDrive FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/skydrive/upload-file-cant-faq)

Besides that the path must contain fewer than 442 characters.